# Ionic File Chooser To Filer According To Mime Type

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to filter the files using file-chooser in Ionic , I want only display document type files , using file-chooser doesn't give me any option(or if it gives I'm not aware of it).
Here I'm writing down the code I tried:-

```
openFile() {
if (this.platform.is('android')) {

  this.fileChooser.open()
    .then(
      uri => {
        alert("aaya"+uri);
        this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri)
          .then(url => {
            alert(url);
            // url is path of selected file
            var fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
            alert(fileName)
            // fileName is selected file name
          })

          .catch(err => alert(err));
      }
    )
    .catch(error => {
     //yha 
      alert(error)
    });
}

}
```

Here When the file explorer is opening it is showing all the files.

**I'm Using the package  "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "4.16.0",**

Answer (score 1):

FileChooser plugin allows you to filter files according to mime type:
Check out the plugin documentation: https://github.com/ihadeed/cordova-filechooser

You can specify mime type in the filter parameter:

```
fileChooser.open(filter, successCallback, failureCallback); // with mime filter
```

FileChooser with mime filter:

```
let filter={ "mime": "application/pdf" }  // text/plain, image/png, image/jpeg, audio/wav etc
 this.fileChooser.open(filter) ... //Rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks For answering ,I tried with this cordova plugin , but I am not able to integrate this with ionic 3.Kindly help.!!!

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Please mark it as an answer so that others can follow up on it. What other problem are you facing with this plugin? I have tried it in my ionic3 app and it works great

Comment: Could u please  help me with the sample code with ionic 3 , the import statement and the filechooser open method. Thanks

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/file-chooser-plugin-in-ionic/111677/3?u=pankajsati

Comment: the link does the same,  it opens the file chooser, without filtering any files.

Comment: Can u provide a working demo, it would be much helpful.Thanks

Comment: if you want multiple mimetype then use this plugin https://github.com/PeterHdd/cordova-filechooser you can then do  `{ "mime": "image/jpeg, application/pdf" };`